# \vfill between items in a list

Tags: spacing, lists, vertical-alignment

I want to create a list and have `\vfill` between all the items. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item One \vfill
\item Two \vfill
\item Three \vfill
\item Four \vfill
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

which works, but would be more elegant if it was like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\itemsep}{\vfill}
\begin{itemize}
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
    \item Four
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

But I get errors (because `\itemsep` is a length?). So how can this be achieved? Further, I would want it only to affect the local environment, rather than globally for all such lists.

Comment: you may take a look at the `enumitem` package

Comment: @Timebandit Thx for the suggestion. I tried `itemsep=\vfill` as an option but that didn't work. Perhaps this is just the same problem as the original, although a solution in `enumitem` might well be neater.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `\vfill` is an instruction that, more or less, tells TeX to "finish the paragraph and insert blank space to fill".
2. `\itemsep` is a rubber length parameter, so `\renewcommand{\itemsep}{\vfill}` is simply wrong.
3. Also `\setlength{\itemsep}{\vfill}`, or the equivalent `itemsep=\vfill` with `enumitem`, is wrong, because `\vfill` isn't a rubber length specification.

Use

```
\setlength{\itemsep}{\fill}
```

or

```
itemsep=\fill
```

As explained in the LaTeX manual, `\vfill` does the same as

```
\par\vspace{\fill}
```

and, similarly but not quite, `\hfill` can be considered as an abbreviation for `\hspace{\fill}`.

If you want also an automatic `\vfill` at the end, I suggest you to define a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the final effect

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{fullpageitemize}
  {\itemize[nolistsep,itemsep=\fill]}
  {\vfill\enditemize}

\begin{document}

\begin{fullpageitemize}
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
    \item Four
\end{fullpageitemize}

\end{document}
```

With `nolistsep` we remove all vertical space, then reset `\itemsep` to `\fill`; finally a `\vfill` is executed just at the end of the environment.

[image]

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Using `\fill` did give a positive reaction, but I would still like to have a `fill` at the final `\item` too. As it stands, your solution pushes the final `\item` directly to the bottom.

Comment: Actually, the first offered solution (`\setlength{\itemsep}{\fill}`) didn't work.

Comment: @Geoff The `\setlength` command must go after `\begin{itemize}` (just like `enumitem` does, essentially).

Comment: Right you are! All the same, both solutions leave no \vfill space at the end.